# Support of fileOperations ClientCapabilities (LSP) in Visual Studio Code 1.54

Tags: visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol

I am implementing a language server and try to integrate it in latest Visual Studio Code 1.54.3. At the moment I try to handle the `fileOperations` capabilities, that have been added to 3.16 protocol version.

If I check the "initialize" message from the client, that is received by the server, the (optional) `fileOperations` attribute is not provided, though. Is is possible that VS Code's LSP client does not support fileOperations capabilities in version 1.54? Is there a way to check the protocol's implementation state?

If this is the case, is there another way to get notified if a file is renamed or deleted? I need this information to reflect it within the server's AST and delete / remap information accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In your VSCode extension, make sure you use the latest language client version. Adding `"vscode-languageclient": "7.0.0"` in package.json did the trick for me.

Comment: Doesnt work for me, I still don't get the expected "fileOperations" sent to my server via the JSON protocol.

Comment: Now I found my bug: Its indeed important to add the right version within the json file, but dont forget to do "npm install" afterwards, too, so that the necessary files are updated as well. Thanks for the hint!